# How to get posts by current tag and category simultaneously in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

I have Post, Tag and Category models. I know how to get posts by tag or posts by category. But I need to get posts by chosen tag and category simultaneously (at one time). Can somebody help? I use Laravel 8.

**Post model**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Tag::class,
            'post_tag',
            'post_id',
            'tag_id'
        );
    }
}
```

**Tag model**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Post::class,
            'post_tag',
            'tag_id',
            'post_id'
        )->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

**Post controller's methods**

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->firstOrFail();
        return view('pages.post', compact('post'));
    }

    public function tag($slug)
    {
        $tag = Tag::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        $posts = $tag->posts()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(7);
        return view('pages.postlist', ['posts'  =>  $posts]);
    }

    public function category($slug)
    {
        $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        $posts = $category->posts()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(7);
        return view('pages.postlist', ['posts'  =>  $posts]);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/posts/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@show')->name('post.show');
Route::get('/posts/tag/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@tag')->name('ptag.show');
Route::get('/posts/category/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@category')->name('pcategory.show');
```

Comment: use multiple `where` in your controller

Comment: I need to take data from different tables. So, I don't understand how to use multiple `where` here.

Comment: try use `whereHas`. Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478498/laravel-eloquent-where-on-join-table/35479118. Also you can use `Query Builder` + `join` + `where` together

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```php
$categoryId = 1;
$tagId = 2;

Post::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
    $query->whereKey($categoryId);
})->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tagId) {
    $query->whereKey($tagId);
})->get();
```